# Ruby Vacuum Gem Amazon Product API "400 Bad Request Error"

Tags: ruby, amazon-product-api

I trying to make example from Vacuum documentation work, but all I got is: Expected(200)<=>Actual(400 Bad Request)

```
require 'vacuum'

request = Vacuum.new ('GB')

request.configure(
    aws_access_key_id: 'XXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key: 'XXXXXXXX',
    associate_tag: 'XXXXXXXX'
)


response = request.item_lookup(
  query: {
    'ItemId' => '0679753354'
  }
)

puts response
```

and I got:

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in `response_call': Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request) (Excon::Errors::BadRequest) 
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/middl ewares/response_parser.rb:8:in `response_call'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:372:in `response'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:236:in `request'
        from (eval):6:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/vacuum-1.4.0/lib/vacuum/request.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Request>'
        from vacuum.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I just installed this gem, created Access Keys Pair and can't move any further. Forgive me being completely new with Ruby.

Comment: Did you register with amazon affiliates? https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum#prerequisite

Comment: Hello, yes I did - I got affiliate account and secure key pair. I read a lot on internet - so some say I need "to sign" my queries - but there is nothing in Vaccuum docs about that, other that I need register my Keys for API queries funcionality - same above I didn't found anything related in docs

Comment: I'm not sure - is that Bad Request related to connectivity or it's just bad (badly formulated) query to API ?

Comment: Vacuum code works fine for me. Check if your keys work fine in amazon scratchpad http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about scratchpad - apparently for some reason my keys wasn't good for API requests. It's working now. Thank you